# Basic iCloud Key-Value storage test failing

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I wanted to test iCloud key-value storage. Here are the steps I took:

1) Purchase apple developer account for about $100, waited for it to activate

2) In the developer area, I created an App ID, an iCloud container, a provisioning profile (iOS Development), and made sure it knew about my personal device.

3) Created a new single-view swift app in XCode

4) Added the following code in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

```
    let keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()

    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        //let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = true
        keyStore.setString("testValue2", forKey: "testKey2")
        let didSync = keyStore.synchronize()
        print("synched: \(didSync)")
    #else
        //let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = false
        let didSync = keyStore.synchronize()
        print("synched: \(didSync)")
        if let theString = keyStore.stringForKey("testKey2") {
            print("the string: \(theString)")
        }
        else {
            print("did not find string with specified key")
        }
    #endif
```

5) Launched the app on the 5s simulator, confirmed that keyStore.synchronize() returns true.

6) Waited 10 seconds

7) Launched the app on my iPhone 6+, confirmed that keyStore.synchronize() returns true.

8) Sadly, it printed out "did not find string with specified key"

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remove the calls to `synchronize`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call `synchronize` in this instance.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010934-CH1-SW29):

> During synchronization between memory and disk, this method updates your in-memory set of keys and values with changes previously received from iCloud

Since you are writing to memory and then immediately calling `synchronize`, your in-memory values will be overwritten by the cached values, which in the case of a brand new app, are empty.  The system has not yet had a chance to update the cache with the value you just wrote.

You should include a call to `synchronize` in `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

> The only recommended time to call this method is upon app launch, or upon returning to the foreground, to ensure that the in-memory key-value store representation is up-to-date.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
    keyStore.synchronize()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.iCloudChangedNotification(_:)), name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification, object: nil)

    keyStore.setString("testValue2", forKey: "testKey2")
    if let theString = keyStore.stringForKey("testKey2") {
        print("the string: \(theString)")
    }
    else {
        print("did not find string with specified key")
    }  
    return true
}

func iCloudChangedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("iCloud changed")
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let changeReason = userInfo[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber {
            print("Change reason = \(changeReason)")
        }
        if let changedKeys = userInfo[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangedKeysKey] as? [String] {
            print("ChangedKeys = \(changedKeys)")
        }          
    }

    let keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()

    if let theString = keyStore.stringForKey("testKey2") {
        print("the string: \(theString)")
    }
    else {
        print("did not find string with specified key")
    }
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    let keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
    keyStore.synchronize()            
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doing that didn't change the results.

Comment: I just noticed that you are attempting to synchronise between two simulators; I assume you have signed in to the same iCloud account on both?  I have updated my code to show how you can register for notifications on the iCloud update

Comment: On the simulator you may also have to use debug->trigger iCloud sync in order to see the changes

Comment: Paulw11, I am attempting to sync between the simulator and a real device. Selecting the Trigger iCloud sync option causes an error dialog to appear:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 2 - Logged out - iCloud Drive is not configured)

Comment: Have you logged into your iCloud account on the simulator?

Comment: I haven't logged in to my iCloud account on the simulator and my personal device. I don't use iCloud personally. Are you saying that end users have to be logged in to their iCloud account just to use basic key-value storage functionality?

Comment: Of course. Otherwise how would the device know which iCloud to store the key/values in?

Comment: I assumed it would key off of the device and app, sort of like NSUserDefaults. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: With iCloud the data will be synchronised between devices with the same iCloud account, so app & device isn't enough; how would it know which devices to put "my" data on?